# SQL Server MDF file missing after "Recovery Pending"

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I'm probably writing in vain, but we have a database in SQL Server 2016 that's showing "Recovery Pending".

When I run

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET EMERGENCY;
```

it tells me that my `.mdf` file cannot be found. And indeed, neither the `.mdf` nor the `.ldf` file seem to exist there anymore.

We did have some disk space issues, but no manual fixes were attempted on databases.

Any way to recover besides using a backup?

Comment: Probably worth asking on dba.stackexchange.